# Is processes terminated when a user locks their account on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, process, lock-screen, lock

So let's say a user is downloading large files where he's going to leave the computer downloading in his office. Will the processes be terminated or paused (not just download but any possible running process) when he put his computer into lock screen (not sleep mode just the lxok function where it requires you to re-enter your password)? Cause we all know that putting a computer into sleep will stop processes so I'm wondering will putting it into lock screen do the same thing or the process will still keep running.

Comment: Locking the screen shouldn't stop the user processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, if the screen is simply locked (ctrl-alt-del), any running process will continue (downloads, macros, etc), unless, you have a process that checks if the user is still there (but that isn't in your problem description so it shouldn't be the case).